# bitwise operation cause Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the bitwise operation in the following code, but it causes a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

 main()
 {
     uint16_t newmss = 1024;
     uint8_t  *opt;
     unsigned int i = 0;

     opt[i] = (newmss & 0xff00) >> 8;
     opt[i+1] = newmss & 0x00ff;

     fprintf(stderr, "opt[0] is %d", opt[0]);
     fprintf(stderr, "opt[1] is %d", opt[1]);

 }
```

compiled with `gcc -g -o shift shift.c`

then execute shift, I got Segmentation fault

```
# ./shift
Segmentation fault

using gdb to debug

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/vincent/shift

root@vincent-desktop:/home/vincent# gdb shift
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/vincent/shift

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804843f in main () at shift.c:11
11      opt[i] = (newmss & 0xff00) >> 8;
```

Could anybody shed some light on what I am doing wrong to cause the Segmentation fault?

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't the shift, it's the fact that you don't allocate memory for `opt`.

One way to fix this is as follows:

```
 uint8_t  opt[2];
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot the basics that I have to allocate space to pointer before using it